# Android. Многопоточность. Почему при удалении Activity из стека задач прерываются все рабочие потоки?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Вопрос следующий:
Если я запускаю 1 или более рабочих потоков в компоненте Android (Например - Activity), а после закрываю этот компонент (удаляю из стека задач), то все рабочие потоки мгновенно прерываются. Я считал, что потоки должны работать вне зависимости от существования активных компонентов, а прерываться - только по завершению процесса.

Comment: Потому что какому-то умному человеку пришло в голову завершать процесс при удалении приложения из стека. При этом может выжить только служба в режиме foreground, да и то она будет перезапущена (насколько я помню).